# Is there a way to get serializer or content-type from inside Catalyst::Controller::REST class?

Tags: perl, rest, catalyst

Generally it seems that the way Catalyst::Controller::REST is that you put a reference into "entity" and then Catalyst::Action::Serialize picks a content-type and a serializer after you're done.

In my case, I may be dealing with very large data and I can't hold the entire thing in memory at once (it's coming from a different server and I'm reformatting and returning it).  If I knew what content-type Serialize was going to choose, I could transform the incoming data and write it to a file as it comes in and then serve it back out from disk.  Is there any way for me to find out what content-type I'm being asked for beyond copying the code in Catalyst::Action::SerializeBase?

The workaround will be to say "I don't care what you asked for, here's your JSON" but it'd be nice to actually provide what's requested. :)

Comment: There is no stored serializer object. It creates that on the fly in https://metacpan.org/source/JJNAPIORK/Catalyst-Action-REST-1.20/lib/Catalyst/Action/Serialize.pm and that will be called automatically to handle the request. You might be able to stop the flow and forward to that thing later.